# Changing variables during if-else if- else statements in C++

Tags: c++, variables

As I'm sure the question makes clear, I'm new and learning and I'm sure many will wonder why ask.....cause I get the rest of it, just not this. I am using C++ and am trying to make a self guessing program, that uses an algorithim given to me. I have played with this section of code multiple ways and so far the one thing I have narrowed down, is what its not doing, and I want to both understand why and how to fix it because nothing I have tried is working. The basic version of the code I have been playing with is this:

```
// test_room.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution 
//begins and ends there. This is where 
//I am going to test some code to understand my mistakes and how to fix 
//them. 
// 

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
char play = 'y';
while (play == 'y')
{
    int bad = 27;
    int a = 50;
    int b = 1;
    int good = ((a - b) / 2);
    int s = 0;


    cout << "\nBegin?";
    cin >> play;
    do
    {

        ++s;
        if (good > bad)
        {
            cout <<"\n" <<good;
            cout <<"\n" << s;
            --a;
        }
        else if (good < bad)
        {
            cout << "\n"<<good;
            cout <<"\n" << s;
            ++b;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "good job";
        }
    } while (s < 50);
}
cout << "\nOK\n";
return 0;
}
```

What my question is I have tried moving the variables, I have fixed brace issues, I have tried using cin>>good>>a or b(depending on >< ) and so far I can not manipulate variables a or b to get it to try to guess or figure out the number 27, all it does is repeat 24 50 times. What do I need to do to change the values of a and b based on the algorithim?

Comment: You need a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: I'd guess that you need to move this line `int good = ((a - b) / 2);` inside the `do..while`loop, before the `if` statement.

Comment: This actually is my rubber duck. It's a barebones, non commented version of the real one I'm writing for a project. I wrote this as an easier way to play with the code to get it right. What I'm not understanding is why the do loop is not changing the values of a and b when it itereates through the do loop? If the do loop can pull the values of good and bad why are they not changing values of a or b? Even the first line changes the value of s, why is it not changing the values of a or b? Here was an version I did with ++ and -- , I also tried cin but neither works.

Comment: If I have to move that line in, wouldn't I have to move the changing variables in as well?

Answer (score 0):

Good and bad are never changed in the loop, I don't really understand the purpose of you algorithm(it looks like a binary search, but not really), but if you aren't changing any values that the if conditions evaluate in the loop, then none of the other conditions will ever be evaluated.

Comment: It is a binary search, from your answer I'm assuming the other comments are right that it needs to be in the do loop? And I also assume the reason it's wrong is because it's not ((a-b)/2)+b?